# Android RadioButton Accelerometer

Tags: android, radio-button, gesture

I have got a listView in my Android Application. 
Each List has a set of radiobuttons. I can check/uncheck radiobuttons using tap gesture.

Is it possible to change the radiobutton selection via some gesture/shake?

Regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible, but there's no 'built in' mechanism for that. 
You can have a look at the [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html), listen for gestures, detect them and then check / uncheck the radio buttons programmatically. You'll have to come up with a 'model of interaction' (I lack the word here) that makes sense to the user, checking radionbuttons with a shake does not seem very natural to me.